# How to sum integers stored in json

Tags: python, json

How can I sum the count values? My json data is as following.

```
{
  "note":"This file contains the sample data for testing",
  "comments":[
    {
      "name":"Romina",
      "count":97
    },
    {
      "name":"Laurie",
      "count":97
    },
    {
      "name":"Bayli",
      "count":90
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? We are going to help you with your code, not code for you!

Comment: You are right sir. i am new here and in Python too, but i really like it and i will learn this.

Answer (score 3):

This is how i did it eventually.

```
import urllib
import json
mysumcnt = 0
input = urllib.urlopen('url').read()

info = json.loads(input)
myinfo = info['comments']

for item in myinfo:
    mycnt = item['count']
    mysumcnt += mycnt
print mysumcnt
```

Comment: That's the way! Remember, next time wrap your code with `s (or select it and press ctrl+k). That will show the code as code and not as text :-)

Answer (score 3):

Using a sum, map and a lambda function

```
import json

data = '''
{
    "note": "This file contains the sample data for testing",
    "comments": [
        {
            "name": "Romina",
            "count": 97
        },
        {
            "name": "Laurie",
            "count": 97
        },
        {
            "name": "Bayli",
            "count": 90
        }
    ]
}
'''

count = sum(map(lambda x: int(x['count']), json.loads(data)['comments']))

print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the JSON is currently a string and not been loaded into a python object you'll need to:

```
import json

loaded_json = json.loads(json_string)
comments    = loaded_json['comments']

sum(c['count'] for c in comments)
```